# Selenium differentiate between same button at different instances

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the process of downloading reports from a site. There are 4 ways to download it.Hence I have 4 loops with try and except.It gets the file name from a file and check one among for ways to extract.
Now the problem is I have same button click event in two loops. Hence the program stops at the first button click event and throws an error instead of going to the next loop.

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id = xpath_name').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    try:
        Long_File()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        try:
            Extreme()
        except NoSuchElementException:
             NoLong_File()

def NoLong_File() :
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('// *[@id = xpath_name_A]').click()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id = xpath_name_B]').click()

def Extreme() :
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('// *[@id = xpath_name_A]').click()
    time.sleep(10)          
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id = xpath_name_C]').click()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id = xpath_name_D]').click()
```

In the above code, `Extreme` and `NoLong_File` have a same button with same class. So instead of goinf to the last loop, the button click event happens at `Extreme` and stops.

Is there a way to differentiate the same button for different instance?

Comment: Post the relevant html and the code for `Extreme` and `NoLong`.

Comment: What do you mean by different instance? Can you not find first the element, and whenever you have it then click it? instead of doing it all in one go. Please explain further what those "4 ways to download" mean. 4 different buttons a select? One same button clicked in different ways...? Not clear. In the code you posted one cannot see 4 loops, there is just a flow control structure for exception handling.

Comment: @Guy please find below the definitions

Comment: @MikeMajara When i say 4 ways , for example I type one report name in search box - it fetches the report  - when i click the report - it goes to ok button and export button - this is one way. Next way is i type another report name in search box - it fetches the report - when i click that report - it goes to ok button and go to different button this time called 'Later' and then at last to third button to download

Comment: When you type a report name in the search box, and this report is shown on display and can be clicked: can you not tell already which kind of download is it going to be? This is, which buttons you expect to find and click? (a) You should find common patterns to your procedure. (b) what is Long_File, NoLong_File, Extreme...? Use meaningful names, it is hard to guess and help if not. Your future self will also be grateful. (c) `time.sleep` is not adviced, libraries based on async provide methods for waiting until available data comes. Search for `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: You can also modify `// *[@id = xpath_name_A]` for meaningful strings that help people here to read your problem, that does not provide info at all. Another option is posting the HTML code your are scraping.

Comment: @MikeMajara I did not get your answer "which kind of download". After the report name is typed in search box , the report name itself will get displayed in the same page beneath text box which is clickable. Hence i use its xpath to click. Till that click event the procedure is same but after which it has 4 ways to download thats why i have used try and exception . And about meaning full names ...well i named it because the file is long and not long...goes on.stop researching whether its good name or meaning full. Yes time.sleep is not good method and ill try with Webdriverwait.

Comment: @MikeMajara thats the xpath name ....when i say xpath_name_A , just to differentiate the next xpath which is different from the previous

Comment: That's the only differentiation you do and it has no value here. Call them something like `// *[@id = xpath_ok_button_that_downloads_report]`, or `// *[@id = xpath_export_button_that_does_nothing]`. Here no one knows your code. Post HTML (asked in first comment) screencaptures, etc. Show some effort to get some help.

Comment: I first thought that code was enough but html content is sensitive otherwise i would have shared.Ill find a way to explain that as well.This is my first post here in stackoverflow .i am learning 'what and how, to post. Your words are not so welcoming , hence your help is great till now.